# Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location

Tags: android, apk

Today I wanted to generate an APK from my app but i got the following error:

**Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location**

Full error report:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:MyApp:assembleRelease]
    Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
    :MyApp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:checkReleaseManifest
    :MyApp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:compileLint
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:checkReleaseManifest
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0856Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGithubJkwiecienEasyImage109Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview200Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary114Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyAppEssentialsLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0856Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGithubJkwiecienEasyImage109Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview200Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary114Library UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :MyApp:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:processReleaseGoogleServices
    :MyApp:generateReleaseResources
    :MyApp:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:lintVitalRelease
    :MyApp:prePackageMarkerForRelease
    :MyApp:transformClassesWithDexForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:validateExternalOverrideSigning
    :MyApp:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :MyApp:zipalignRelease
    Unable to open 'C:\Users\MyApp-release.apk' as zip archive
    Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:zipalignRelease'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I only get this error if i want to build an APK, **I can run my app in debug mode.**

I have searched the interwebz bout didnt found any solution, only some google forums but not anything that I could use for solution.

M**aybe the the apk generation is not failing because of this**, but the message don't really contians any other issues, as far as I see.

Please advice me if you can.

Comment: On a side note, I think you have two different issues, the answer I gave below should fix the warning you gave in the title, but according to log, it fails when ZipAligning. Seems like a permission issue or something. In any case, you should ask a new question specific to that issue if it persists.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by upgrading SDK which has some changes in package names. Since this is just a warning, it could safely be ignored.

Anyway, to remove the warning,remove all `Android SDK Build Tools 19.x`. It should only show `Android SDK Buld Tools 19.1` afterward. Install that version
back, and you should be good to go.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199518