# error after updating sdk

Tags: android, gradle, android-sdk-2.3

After sdk updating and upper my libs in gradle-file, AS offer me to change gradle version from 2.0.0-aplha6 to stable 2.1.2. Here's project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

After clean/rebuild/run project i got an error:

```
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'C:\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidStudioProjects\labradoor\app\twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)
```

So, last time i fixed this bug using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'` but now i can't do that. How should i solve this problem? Please help!

Comment: try to change build tool version

Comment: i have compileSdkVersion 23 and buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" now. What version should i set?

Comment: try to change 23.0.2

Comment: got the same error :(

Comment: you have required twitter library? if not than remove from project

Comment: yes, it required in my project

Comment: check your path of sdk to android studio is right or not?
tools>Android>Sdk Manager

Comment: yea, the path is right.. =(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116375/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-android-android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Solution

To remove the warning,remove all Android SDK Build Tools 19.x. It should only show Android SDK Buld Tools 19.1 afterward. Install that version back, and you should be good to go.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896916/observed-package-id-add-onsaddon-google-apis-google-19-in-inconsistent-locati)